# Double integral over a not-aligned square

Tags: integration, area

I am studying multivariable calculus and came across a question asking me to evaluate a double integral of F(x,y) over a square, but with vertices at (0,0),(2,1),(3,-1), and (1,-2). Clearly the reigon is not bounded by horizontal and vertical lines, so I'm having trouble coming up with the bounds for my intergal. How can I use an iterated integral to calculate this?

Comment: Given that it's a square, the equations of each of the sides will look like $a_1x+b_1y=c_1,d_1$ and $a_2x+b_2y=c_2,d_2$. Use a change of variables where $u=a_1x+b_1y$ and $v=a_2x+b_2y$. Now the bounds for your integral will be constants.

Comment: You have two choices here. Ninad Munshi has given you the one that is simpler for this problem. The other choice works more generally, which is to figure out the two functions $y_0(x), y_1(x)$ that trace the top and bottom of the domain for each $x$, then $$\iint_S F(x,y)\,dydx = \int_0^3\left(\int_{y_0(x)}^{y_1(x)} F(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx$$